# Does ReSharper 9.2 support intellisense for ASP.NET 5 TagHelpers

Tags: resharper, intellisense, asp.net-core, tag-helpers

Visual Studio 2015 RTM supports intellisense for TagHelpers, but if ReSharper installed this ability disappears. Is it possible to configure somehow, or is this an ReSharper issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the moment TagHelpers support is planned for ReSharper 10. See [YouTrack issue RSRP-427939](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-427939).

Comment: I'm using Resharper 10.0.2 and it's still not available.

Comment: Yep. Has been moved to 10.1. See "fix version" in the linked issue.

Answer (score 2):

It's a known [ReSharper issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-447314).